# To maintain position of child divs wrt to parent background image

Tags: css, angular, css-transforms

I have parent div having a background image and inside this parent, it has child divs.
When the parent div is displayed in smaller size say width 50% then I place the divs using top and left the property at the exact same position I would like to.
Till here everything worked as expected now when I try to display the parent div with 100% width, the background image obviously also fills up the parent div now the issue is
the child elements do not move wrt to the background image.
I guess transform could be the solution but don't know-how and moreover, I also want to scale the child divs wrt to the parent that also transform provides scale but don't know how to use.

I have tried giving position relative and using top and left positions, they place the child divs in expected positions but when size changes of the parent div they do not maintain their pos wrt to the background image

```
<div id="parent" class="dropzone" [ngStyle]=" 
      {'width':'40%','background-image': 'url('+abcurl+')',
       'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-position': 'center', 
       'background-size': '100% 100%', 'border':'1px solid black', 
       'height':'340px', 'position': 'relative'}">

  <div id= "child" class="box" 
       *ngFor="let existingZone of floor.droppeditem"
       [ngStyle]="{'position':'absolute', 'top.px': existingZone.spans[1], 
                 'left.px': existingZone.spans[0]}">
    {{ existingZone.main }}
  </div>

 </div>
```

CSS

parent ngStyle displayed under Styles and class

```
element.style {
 width: 1353px;
 background-image: url(abcurl)
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 340px;
 position: absolute;
}

.dropzone {
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 20px 0;
 background: lightgray;
 min-height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

child ngStyle displayed under Styles and class

```
element.style {
 position: relative;
 top: 92px;
 left: 194px;
}

.box {
  background: #BADA55;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: The box 403 should stay on top of text Office 100 sq feet as in the initial

Comment: Don't use a background image...use an *actual* image. They don't scale in the same way. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha

Comment: @Paulie_D  The image I am getting as a response from backend

Comment: Then that just makes it need JS I'd suggest. Background images don't scale the same way in HTML images so positioning over a bg image doesn't really work the way you think it will.

Comment: @Paulie_D it would be great if you could give some detail of the link you posted as in how it is being handled and I can try it out right away and accept your answer

Comment: @Paulie_D  So should I put some css calcutaions so that when the parent div size changes the child div can move accordingly, also I have transform property of the child divs if that can help

Comment: In the link you don't need transforms... the pin is positioned absolutely on top of the image parent using *percentages* which means that as the image scales the perentages still work out. That's not the same as with a background image which doesn't scale proportionally to itself but rather the element size.

Comment: Then can I use the image in a way your provided link does, else what is approach should I take becoz keeping the position wrt to image is critical for my requirement, thanks for patiently answering

Comment: It's all there in the link...just try it out.

Comment: @Paulie_D  I guess it will work, as everything I had is the same as your code pen link, the thing I tried is I had changed the top and left values and unit from px to% from console itself , however I get this top and left values in px from a different screen, so how can this be changed to percentage or when I calculate the top and left in other screen there itself I have to calculate in percentage, there I am using getBoundingClientRect() which I think calcukates and gives me in px, please suggest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197946/discussion-between-enthu-and-paulie-d).